# How do I tell if an SPListItem is a document or a folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a loop that is looping through a document library like in the example below.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in DocumentLibrary)
{
}
```

How do I tell if the `SPListItem` is a document or a folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.folder.aspx) property of the list item will be `null` if the item is not a folder, so you can write:

```
public bool IsFolder(SPListItem item)
{
    return item.Folder != null;
}
```

In the same way, the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.file.aspx) property of the item will be `null` if the item is not a document. However, the documentation advises against using this property in that case:

> The `File` property also returns `null` if
>   the item is a folder, or if the item
>   is not located in a document library,
>   although it is not recommended that
>   you call this property in these cases.

An alternate way is to check the [BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.basetype.aspx) property of the list:

```
public bool IsDocument(SPListItem item)
{
    return !IsFolder(item)
        && item.ParentList.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use **SPFileSystemObjectType** enumeration.
Here's a sample...

```
foreach (SPListItem item in docLib.Items)
{
    if (item.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder)
    {
        // item is a folder 
        ...
    }
    else if (item.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.File)
    {
        // item is a file
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (item.Folder!=null) 
  // item is Folder and Folder will hold the SPFolder class
```

Comment: Correct answer 7 minutes earlier! +0. Life is unfair!!! ;) Just kidding +1 to you too.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( item["ContentType"].ToString() == "Folder")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the safest way is to check the [FileSystemObjectType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.filesystemobjecttype.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (oitem.ContentType.Name == spWeb.AvailableContentTypes[SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Folder].Name)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Folder Name: " + oitem.Name.ToString());
                        }
```